# Upload image to server as base64 string without reducing the quality

Tags: android, image-uploading

I am trying to upload images to remote server. While compressing the image quality is getting reduced and Without compressing the image is covered with a white layer. How to upload a good quality image to the server.

```
    private void uploadImage(String photoPath) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions);
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 9;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    mPhotoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if (mPhotoBitmap != null) {
        mPhotoBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] ImgbyteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        photoBase64 = new String(Base64.encode(ImgbyteArray, Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
}
```

Tried like this but the base64 giving a white image...

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: where is your attemps, then you can do that by google searching.

Comment: I have edited my ques with what I have tried..

Comment: The way you convert the byte-array to a String is not safe to use. See my answer below on how to do this in a secure way. This might actually be the reason why you get a blank image.

Comment: @Erik Hellman... I have tried with your code, getting the same.. actually what I'm trying to do is selecting image from gallery/capturing image..

Comment: Ok. Try to display the Bitmap in an ImageView first. If that doesn't work you know that the problem is not with converting it to a base64 string. 

My guess is that you're not able to read the Bitmap you picked in the gallery.

Comment: Okay.. I'll try that and let you know..

Comment: Now im getting  decoder->decode returned false error..

Comment: I tried to decode in online converter.. the image is shown on top in very small space then full of black..

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to upload it as a base64 string without reducing quality you can use the following code.

```
public static String getBase64ForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: That means the original Bitmap is white. The code above doesn't touch the content of the original image. 

Try to display the Bitmap in an ImageView before you convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

most of the people use this code to upload image on server.

```
public static String getBase64ForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

but here we need to change it .PNG to JPEG with 100 percent quality compression  rate, if we compress it more then it help to send image to server quickly but you can loose the quality so new code will be like this :

```
public static String getBase64ForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```